# Google appengine delete_serving_url not working?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm quite new to appengine, so this is probably a simple problem to fix.

In my website I use the following to get a serving URL

```
image_url = get_serving_url(blob_key, size=450, crop=False, secure_url=True)
```

I display the image with no problem, however, I would like to remove it after it has been used, but when I call

```
delete_serving_url(blob_key)
```

I get the following error

```
NameError: global name 'delete_serving_url' is not defined
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because both the functions get_serving_url and delete_serving_url are defined within the [images module](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/). So you call them like:

```
from google.appengine.api import images
images.get_serving_url(...)
images.delete_serving_url(...)
```

The `get_serving_url` part is probably working because you have an import statement like `from google.appengine.api.images import get_serving_url`.